# Crystal Reports in 2010 now is not working

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

We had our Crystal Reports report sheets in 2008 working and when we moved to 2010, some of them which their datasources were binded to dataset and datatables are not working. Anyone knows of a reason? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Happened to me too. Basically there is a new CR for VS 2010 that you need to install it manually. It used to be come in the box with VS but not for VS2010. You need to do code changes. Word of caution to pay attention to the 64 or 32 bit CR.

You can download it http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/crystalreports-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

In case you're looking for Crystal Reports for VS 2010, look here:  http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp

You'll need one of the first two downloads to install Crystal Reports into Visual Studio.  Then you'll need one of the other downloads to distribute the runtime files.  For example, if you're hosting a web application on a 64-bit server, you'll need to run the last download in the list on that server.

Comment: But I am using an stand-alone crystal report IDE not the one in Visual Studio 2010 IDE. Does this make any diffenrece?